# How Can I construct native query in spring boot with dynamic param as placeholder based on condition?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using MSSQL server as DB and the method in the repository layer of my spring boot project:

```
List<Object[]> SummaryData(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate,
                                           @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate, List<Integer> cNoList);
```

here `cNoList` may contain only 0 or some values.
i want when cNoList contains values such as (45,30,20 etc.) then the below query will execute:

```
    SELECT 'CUSTOMER' as title_key, COUNT(*) as total_count FROM LOGIN_TABLE lg left join USER_TABLE ut on lg.u_id = ut.tid_no where lg.user_type = 'CUSTOMER' and lg.is_verified = 1 and 
lg.sys_time BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2 AND cId in (?3)
```

when cNoList contains only 0 then the last part of the above query --> "AND cId in (?3)" will not execute just like below:

```
SELECT 'CUSTOMER' as title_key, COUNT(*) as total_count FROM LOGIN_TABLE lg left join USER_TABLE ut on lg.u_id = ut.tid_no where lg.user_type = 'CUSTOMER' and lg.is_verified = 1 and lg.sys_time BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2
```

i have made an attempt like below:

```
"DECLARE @part VARCHAR(100) = ''; \n" +
                    "DECLARE @region_no INT = 420;\n" +
                    "DECLARE @start Datetime = '2022-07-01 00:00:00';\n" +
                    "DECLARE @end Datetime = '2023-01-17 23:59:59';\n" +
                    "DECLARE @tp VARCHAR(100) = 'CUSTOMER';\n" +
                    "SET @part = (CASE WHEN @region_no != 0 THEN 'and region_no = ' + CAST(@region_no AS VARCHAR(100)) ELSE '' END);\n" +
                    "EXEC ('SELECT ''' + @tp + ''' as title_key, COUNT(*) as total_count FROM LOGIN_TABLE lg left join USER_TABLE ut on lg.u_id = ut.tid_no where lg.user_type = ''' + @tp + ''' and lg.is_verified = 1 and \n" +
                    "lg.sys_time BETWEEN\n" +
                    "CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + @start + ''', 120) \n" +
                    "AND\n" +
                    "CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + @end + ''', 120) ' + @part)", nativeQuery = true)
                    
List<Object[]> SummaryData(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate,
                                           @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate, List<Integer> cNoList);
```

this query executes well with the static value @region_no, @start, @end but these values will be assigned dynamically.

issues I am facing :

- i tried putting a placeholder "?3" but not working. how can I put a placeholder like "?3" instead of 420 in this line "DECLARE @region_no INT = 420" ?
  (the value of @region_no needs to be something of type array of int but i guess it is of type only int here)
- how can i use the placeholder for "DECLARE @start Datetime = '2022-07-01 00:00:00';\n", i want to use something like

  "DECLARE @start Datetime = ?1;"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `:param` instead of `?1`.

For example:

```
"DECLARE @part VARCHAR(100) = ''; \n" +
        "DECLARE @region_no INT = :cNoList;\n" +
        "DECLARE @start Datetime = :startDate;\n" +
        "DECLARE @end Datetime = :endDate;\n" +
        "DECLARE @tp VARCHAR(100) = 'CUSTOMER';\n" +
        "SET @part = (CASE WHEN @region_no != 0 THEN 'and region_no = ' + CAST(@region_no AS VARCHAR(100)) ELSE '' END);\n" +
        "EXEC ('SELECT ''' + @tp + ''' as title_key, COUNT(*) as total_count FROM LOGIN_TABLE lg left join USER_TABLE ut " +
        "on lg.u_id = ut.tid_no where lg.user_type = ''' + @tp + ''' and lg.is_verified = 1 and \n" +
        "lg.sys_time BETWEEN\n" +
        "CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + @start + ''', 120) \n" +
        "AND\n" +
        "CONVERT(DATETIME, ''' + @end + ''', 120) ' + @part)", nativeQuery = true)

    List<Object[]> SummaryData(@Param("startDate") LocalDateTime startDate,
                               @Param("endDate") LocalDateTime endDate, 
                               @Param("cNoList") List<Integer> cNoList);
```